# CountDown Timer - messy function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, timer, countdowntimer

I've got a code with CountDown Timer function,
But i have a problem, that i can't solve - If i click another time on button, it makes mess.
How can i make it to count from new time / or does'nt make double count if it still counting?
Why is it doing that?

```js
  function myFunctionTimer() {
      var timeoutHandle;
      function countdown(minutes) {
          var seconds = 60;
          var mins = minutes
          function tick() {
              var counter = document.getElementById("time");
              var current_minutes = mins-1
              seconds--;
              counter.innerHTML =
              current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
              if( seconds > 0 ) {
                  timeoutHandle=setTimeout(tick, 1000);
      }
       if( seconds == 0 ) {
      window.location.reload()
      }else {
                  if(mins > 1){
                     setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);}}}tick();}
      countdown(1);};
```

```html
 <button onclick="myFunctionTimer()">Click me</button>
 
 <div class="OfertaWazna" >Counter: <span id="time"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **make the timeout variable accessible** to your `myFunctionTimer`, so that it can **clear the same** when called next time.

```
function myFunctionTimer( ele ) {

  //attach the timer to the element
  var tickTimer = ele.tickTimer;
  if ( tickTimer )
  {
     clearTimeout( tickTimer );
  }
   // rest of the code

}
```

Also

- No need to create two timers, one is enough. Just check if the final time-value is 0 or not.
- Use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`, it is less intrusive and more readable.

**Demo**

```js
function myFunctionTimer( ele ) {
 
  //attach the timer to the element
  var tickTimer = ele.tickTimer;
  if ( tickTimer )
  {
     clearTimeout( tickTimer );
  }

  function countdown(minutes) {
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes

    function tick() {
      var counter = ele;
      var current_minutes = mins - 1
      seconds--;
      counter.innerHTML =
        current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
      if (seconds > 0) {
        ele.tickTimer = setTimeout(tick, 1000); //set the timer here
      }      
    }
    tick();
  }
  countdown(1);
}

document.querySelector( "button" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
   myFunctionTimer( document.getElementById( "time" ) );
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<div class="OfertaWazna">Counter: <span id="time"></span></div>
```